# Cannot show <div> from CSS in Wordpress Text Widget

Tags: css, wordpress

Can not show `<div>` from css in Wordpress Text Widget
in Text widget:

```
<div class=”deffgall-cutlure” ></div>
```

style.css

```
.deffgall-cutlure {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#06C;
}
```

Also tried [Enhanced Text Widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/enhanced-text-widget/), which must to show with custom css, not working also.

**Html Works** if is typed directly onto the Text Widget, but can`t respond from CSS.

Any ideas, pls?

Comment: What's the URL of the page you're doing this work on? Also, just to clarify you're not trying to write CSS directly in a WordPress Text Widget, are you? That definitely won't work as it only accepts plain text and HTML.

Comment: you probably have a typo in your selector.
shouldn't it be `.defgall-culture` instead of `defgall-cutlure`?
EDIT: Nevermind, after the edit it's obviously not a typo

Comment: .deffgal-cutlure { display:block;
position:relative;
min-width:100px;
min-height:100px;
background-color:#06C; }//// this i put in theme style.css and put /// <div class=”deffgall-cutlure” ></div> /// onto WP text widget, but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use your browsers "Inspect Element" tools to see if another style is overwriting your style and to see if your style is being applied at all (maybe hinting at a different problem, like your style sheet isn't being included by WrodPress)

[image]

If it is being overridden by another style declaration, then make sure you add the `!important` flag after your `display: block` like so to ensure that it takes precedent

[image]

Comment: Styles inspector only say : inherited from another element. IDK why the div from the css not shown..